# Update bootstrap progress bar on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot figure out why my javascript doesn't work.

```
  //Update Progress Bar
$('#photoUpload-name').blur(function () {
    var validName = $('#photoUpload-name').val();
    if (validName > 1) {
        $(function () {
            $(".progress-bar").css("width", "50%");
        });
    }
});
```

I know my project is set up correctly because $(".progress-bar").css("width", "50%"); works outside the function.

After the user, in this case, fills out their name and the input loses focus, I want it to check that there was at least 2 characters entered (validName > 1) then if there is, to update the progress bar.

I've tried different variations of this, using focusout and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try this: " if (validName > 1) $(".progress-bar").css("width", "50%"); "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check `lenght` you need:

```
$('#photoUpload-name').val().length;
```

Because `$('#photoUpload-name').val()` just get the value.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/mmq14xp7/)